# How can I make this setTimeout call first thing on page load THEN wait five seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, settimeout, polling

I have this method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    var rootPath = getRootPartofPathName();
    (function poll() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: rootPath + '/data/notifications?method=getNotificationSizes',
                success: function (data) {
                    handleNotifications(data); 
                },
                complete: poll
            });
        }, 5000);
    })();
});
```

But it only calls 5 seconds after the page has loaded. How can I make it start polling on first page load?

Comment: And not call the function twice, right?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question....change 5000 to 1 would call the setTimeout right away....then wait 5 seconds to do what? The callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the `timeout` in the callback, and there's no need for the self-executing function either, then simply call `poll()` on page load:

```
function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: rootPath + '/data/notifications?method=getNotificationSizes',
        success: function (data) {
            handleNotifications(data); 
            setTimeout(poll, 5000);
        },
        complete: function() {

        }
    });
}

poll();
```

Comment: Hi so I enclosed the function within brackets because they did it here: http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery. 

Would there be any differences or drawbacks in your normal function?

Comment: @JohnathanAu -- No - you simply had a self-executing function - the code above is perfectly fine.